# Pandas dataframe only select the columns that have all True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe df, I need to select the columns that have only True values

```
df = 
      A      B      C       D       E
    True    False   True   False   True
```

Output should be

```
output = [A, C, E]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try boolean indexing with `all` (for *only True values*):

```
df.columns[df.all()]
```

Output:

```
Index(['A', 'C', 'E'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: If you want just the list, you can add to_list() to the end `df.columns[df.all()].to_list()`

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating through it and putting the keys in a list (you can easily modify this to result in a dict, though).

```
result = []
for i in df.keys():
    if df[i].all():
        result.append(i)
```

Comment: This does not provide you with the desired answer. You need to add the .all(). The updated code will look like this `if df[i].all():`

Comment: My apologies. I have no experience with ```pandas```, so I assumed it was similar to to a ```dict```.